# Script to Align Text layer to center of another reference layer

Tags: photoshop-script

The contents to the text layer are added from csv import. Some are short length and some are long, contain 2 words and take up 2 lines in the layer. What I need is after the content is added, the layer should be horizontally and vertically aligned to another layer. I want to do this alignment using a script.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var grps = doc.layerSets;
var pnamegrp = grps.getByName('Group 1');
var childlyr = pnamegrp.layers.getByName('child');
childlyr.textItem.contents = pname; //come from a csv file 

var parentlyr=  pnamegrp.layers.getByName('ReferenceRectangle');
Align_HorizCenter_VerticalCenter_withreference( childlyr , parent);


function Align_HorizCenter_VerticalCenter_withreference( child, parent){
  //need help to write this
}
```

I am using Photoshop cc 2015 and JavaScript jsx file scripting.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What are you stuck with? At the moment this looks like a job description, not a question

Answer (score 0):

Just incase somebody is looking for a solution. Translate is the method to move layer. The number of pixels to be moved can be determined by the difference in the width between the target and reference layer.

```
var startRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.INCHES;

var doc = app.activeDocument; 
var grps = doc.layerSets;
var pnamegrp = grps.getByName('Group 1');
var pnamelyr= pnamegrp.layers.getByName('pname'); //target
var pnameREF = pnamegrp.layers.getByName('Rectangle 1'); //reference var    LB = pnameREF.bounds;
var RWidth = (LB[2].value) - (LB[0].value);
var RHeight = (LB[3].value) - (LB[1].value);
pnamelyr.textItem.contents = pnamearr[i];
LB = pnamelyr.bounds;
TWidth = (LB[2].value) - (LB[0].value);
THeight = (LB[3].value) - (LB[1].value);



var OffsetX =  (RWidth - TWidth)/2;
var OffsetY =  (RHeight -  THeight)/2;


pnameTGT.translate(OffsetX,OffsetY); //move layer by offset pixels from the current position
```